# Cannot find -lQtAV

Tags: c++, qt, dll, linker

I'm trying to compile the tests for QtAV project. I followed the steps described here: https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/wiki/Use-QtAV-In-Your-Projects

Everything went fine until I tried to compile some of the examples. I get this error: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQtAV

I think the libraries  (QtAV1.dll, QtAVWidgets1.dll etc.) are in place, located in c:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin\ in my case. I even successfully compiled a QML test application using QtAV for Windows and Android.

But the examples won't compile and I'm not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to figure out why.

The linker tells you that it can't find `libQtAV.lib`

> I think the libraries (QtAV1.dll, QtAVWidgets1.dll etc.) are in place

Above libraries (`DLL`s) are needed at runtime. At *linktime*, you need `LIB`s, not `DLL`s.

You probably need to add: `-L c:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib` to your link line.